# Ubuntu Gnome 3.18, Dark theme and Raw Therapee

Tags: 16.04, gnome, themes, fonts, gtk

### Problem:

Raw Therapee (4.2) looks bad when I activate the dark theme in "Tweak Tool", with "bad" I mean, white controls, unreadable text, dark background with dark fonts...

### Steps to reproduce it:

- Fresh installation of Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.1 x64
- Installation of Raw Therapee.
- Activation of dark theme.

Probably the issue affects other programs but I've not checked it.

Answer (score 0):

After search for a while in Google I figured out that the problem is related with gtk, gtk2 to be more precise.

We just need to install gtk2-engines

```
$ sudo apt install gtk2-engines
```

And that's it. Restart Raw Therapee and everything is it should be.

I hope this can help to somebody with similar problems.